# How to dismantle/repair a broken umbrella

Tags: repair

I have a [doppler foldable umbrella](https://www.umbrellaworld.co.uk/doppler-magic-xm-oversize-auto-folding-umbrella-black.html) but it broke after few years of good service. Each of its "arms"(is this the right term in English?) has three foldable parts and the thing that broke is the third part of one of them. It seems it the metal got rusty and with time it broke. This is my best effort of a picture where it broke 

 [image: broken part] 
I have a second older umbrella that is the same so I thought I could take this part from it. However I am having trouble dismantling the junction(don't know the right name in English). Here are two photos from both sides of it 

 [image: side a] and [image: side b]. 
I need to remove the small metallic bit holding the two black parts. These pictures also show a different angle of where the umbrella broke.

My idea is to take apart this bit on both umbrellas and carefully cut the threads holding the fabric on both umbrellas. Then I will replace the broken part with a good one from the other umbrella and I sew the fabric back. I think I will need to use wire or something similar to fix the joint.

Does anyone have an advice on how to dismantle such junction? Do you have any other idea of how to repair my broken umbrella?

Answer (score 1):

In English, the 'arms' of your umbrella are called "spokes." I found this at [**instructables**](http://www.instructables.com/id/Dont-chuck-that-broken-umbrella/)

[image: repair umbrella spoke]

To remove the fastener on the spoke, there are a [number of methods](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Rivets). Because these fasteners are small, traditional rivet removal techniques may be "overkill" and you could break the spoke, the connector or injure yourself from slippage. See if you are able to use a small sharp chisel and small tack hammer to loosen the tabs. If so, continue in this fashion. If the parts are too small to do this effectively, move on to finer tools. Best bet I think, would be prying up each tab where it attaches at the connector and then using a small pair of needlenose pliers to grab and wiggle out the fastener.

I haven't tried to repair an umbrella in this condition; just bought a new one. I think it's possible, just time consuming and the possibility of high frustration factor based on the small, cheap fastener. Good luck and please let us know how it went. (Predicting new umbrella purchase)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I also found this article but it does not explain how to take apart the spokes.  In order to replace the broken one I need to remove it first

Comment: Well, that process will be a bit tedious, but if you want to spend the time and effort to do so, then make sure you have the replacement spokes before taking the umbrella apart. Next, you'll want to make sure you have adequate light and a surface like a desk or a kitchen table to work. I'll add removing the  fasteners to my answer.